# How are equal hashes from multiple gitlab.rb files merged?

Tags: ruby, configuration, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, ruby-hash

In a GitLab configuration file (`gitlab.rc`) an additional config file can be referenced:

```rb
from_file "/home/admin/external_gitlab.rb"
```

The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#load-external-configuration-file-from-non-root-user) states the following:

> Any configuration that is set in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb after from_file is included, takes precedence over the configuration from the included file.

Does this imply that a hash with equal names (e.g. gitlab_rails['env']) is overwritten? Or are only the keys overwritten?

### Use case

I'd like to make an additional `proxy_gitlab.rb`, which is referenced from the `gitlab.rb` with some proxy settings:

```
gitlab_rails['env'] = {
    "http_proxy" => "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.com:8080",
    "https_proxy" => "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.com:8080"
#    "no_proxy" => ".yourdomain.com"  # Wildcard syntax if you need your internal domain to bypass proxy
}
```

However, if a `gitlab_rails['env']` is defined in the main `gitlab.rb`, these settings will not be in the final config if the hash from the main `gitlab.rb` overwrites the hash from the `proxy_gitlab.rb`. If however the two hashes are combined this solution would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The hashes are not merged: the latest loaded hash takes precedence.**

I've tried the following:

`gitlab.rb`:

```rb
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = {
  'main' => {
    'label' => 'LDAP',
    'host' =>  'ldap.mydomain.com',
    'port' => 636,
    'uid' => 'sAMAccountName',
    'encryption' => 'simple_tls',
    'base' => 'dc=example,dc=com',
  }
}

from_file '/etc/gitlab/gitlab-secret.rb'
```

`gitlab-secret.rb`:

```rb
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = {
  'main' => {
    'password' => 'secret',
  }
}
```

When checking the config with `gitlab-ctl show-config`, the following result was shown:

```rb
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = {
  'main' => {
    'password' => 'secret',
  }
}
```

Note: what I've attempted to do is to separate the config and the secret. This can be done for the LDAP as described in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/#configure-ldap).